# Retrieving data by considering a value from another table

Tags: mysql

**Some Context:**

I am trying to display all the items with the highest quantity in another table.

I want to display the best-selling items sorted by 'quantity' in the OrderItems table. A productId with a quantity of '5' should come first, then the product quantity of '4'..so on and so forth.

I am only able to retrieve the items that matched the productId, size, and color, but am stuck on how to factor in the quantity.

**OrderItems Table**

| orderItemsId | orderId | productId | quantity | size | colors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 48 | 1 | 1 | small | black |
| 2 | 48 | 2 | 2 | small | black |
| 3 | 48 | 3 | 5 | small | black |

**Product Table**

| productindex | productId | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Addidas |
| 2 | 2 | Nike |
| 3 | 3 | NewBalance |

So, the items displayed should be productId 3,2,1

I just need to sum all the productId quantity, regardless of size and color. and is it to retrieve from the products table by ascending order

This is a small code, just to retrieve the products that happen to be in the orderItems  table.

```
SELECT * from Product
inner join OrderItems ON Product.productId = OrderItems.productId where Product.size = OrderItems.size and Product.color = OrderItems.colors
```

Comment: you can have multiple condition on the `on` clause in the sql, have you tried that? also, i suppose you already knew the drill: [post table structure as a text not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403703).

Comment: oh right, regarding `quantity`, can't you group by the orders by `productid`, `size`, and `colors` then `sum` the `quantity` columns before joining them?

Comment: @BagusTesa i have made the necessary edits, could you help me out with this, i have been stuck for days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by sum():

```
SELECT Product.* from Product inner join OrderItems
ON Product.productId = OrderItems.productId AND
Product.size = OrderItems.size and Product.color = OrderItems.colors
GROUP BY Product.productId
ORDER BY sum(OrderItems.quantity) DESC;
```